# sql on java (query)

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to do a SELECT query in SQL in Java (Netbeans) using Access as SGBD but I have an error
What am I doing wrong? It says syntax error in FROM. What is really strange is that the query works well in Access, and other (simpler) queries were correctly implemented in the Java script. I did not found doc on that in the books I bought or even on the Net because it's often with less tables ! Thank you in advance –

```
PreparedStatement ps = cnx.prepareStatement("SELECT Client.Nom , Facture.Date_Achat , Client.Prénom , Facture.N°Fac , SUM(Contient1.Quantité1*PrixAchatMonture)AS Somme "+ 
"FROM Facture , Client , Contient1 , Monture "+
"ON Facture.N°Client=Client.N°Client AND Facture.N°Fac=Contient1.N°Fac AND Contient1.IDM=Monture.IDM "+
"WHERE Client.Nom =? AND Client.Prénom=? "+
"GROUP BY Client.Nom, Facture.Date_Achat, Client.Prénom, Facture.N°Fac",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        // ! au sens de la jointure pour l'affichage
```

> [Microsoft][Pilote ODBC Microsoft Access] Syntax error in From

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
PreparedStatement ps = cnx.prepareStatement("SELECT Client.Nom , Facture.Date_Achat , Client.Prénom , Facture.N°Fac , SUM(Contient1.Quantité1 * Monture.PrixAchatMonture) AS Somme "+ 
"FROM Facture , Client , Contient1 , Monture "+
"ON Facture.N°Client=Client.N°Client AND Facture.N°Fac=Contient1.N°Fac AND Contient1.IDM=Monture.IDM "+
"WHERE Client.Nom =? AND Client.Prénom=? "+
"GROUP BY Client.Nom, Facture.Date_Achat, Client.Prénom, Facture.N°Fac",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Comment: PreparedStatement ps = cnx.prepareStatement("SELECT Client.Nom , Facture.Date_Achat , Client.Prénom , Facture.N°Fac , SUM(Contient1.Quantité1 * Monture.PrixAchatMonture) AS Somme "+ 
"FROM Facture "+
"INNER JOIN Client ON Facture.N°Client=Client.N°Client "+
"INNER JOIN Contient1 ON Facture.N°Fac=Contient1.N°Fac "+
"INNER JOIN Monture ON Contient1.IDM=Monture.IDM "+
"WHERE Client.Nom =? AND Client.Prénom=? "+
"GROUP BY Client.Nom, Facture.Date_Achat, Client.Prénom, Facture.N°Fac ",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);